# problem with Spring Security with microservices

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, microservices

Project is divided on 
   ----API Gateway (Zuul)
                    --- authentification services (Login/Signup , generete JWT Token)
                    ---  CaclulateFees services
                    ---  Calculaterate Services
My need is to generete token on authentification services with JWT ( that's Ok)
i need on each other services to validate token before execting the method.

i have add needed librairy to CalculateFees and then implements WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        // We don't need CSRF for this example
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                // dont authenticate this particular request
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate", "/register" ).permitAll().
                 anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
                // store user's state.
                exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

after that i implements CustomRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter , to check Token and initiate a SecurityContext

Problem i keep getting 401 UNAUTHORIZED wherver i try to call the services and query not getting to customrequestfilter.

Please Help , i've try so many combinisation and configuration without succeeded.

I'm using SPRING BOOT 2.2.6.

below code for token validation

```
@Component
public class CustomRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

     @Autowired
     private CustomJwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

     @Autowired
     private CustomJwtTokenProvider jwtTokenUtil;

     @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
            final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            Long userID = null;
            String jwtToken = null;
            // JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get
            // only the Token
            if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
                try {
                    userID = jwtTokenUtil.getUserIdFromJWT(jwtToken);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
                } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                    System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
                }
            } else {
                logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
            }
            // Once we get the token validate it.
            if (userID != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
                UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserById(userID);
                // if token is valid configure Spring Security to manually set
                // authentication
                if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken)) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                    usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                    // After setting the Authentication in the context, we specify
                    // that the current user is authenticated. So it passes the
                    // Spring Security Configurations successfully.
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
                }
            }
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

}
```

Comment: add code where you are generating token and authenticating each request ?

Comment: i've added the code , thanks for your help (bow)

Comment: hard to debug with this code.. debug part where you issue token and `jwtTokenUtil.getUserIdFromJWT(jwtToken)`

Comment: my problem is that this class is not invoked , i'm kicked out by the 401 before call came here so i can't debug nothing. thanks for your help

Comment: Have you added the customrequest filter to your filter chain in your security config class?

Comment: Yes , problem solved by desactivate spring security auto configuration and then add component scan. thanks everyone